# Windows Database service that uses interface for multiple database types

Tags: c#, postgresql, service, interface, sql-server-ce

I am new to window services. I have one that does certain things to either a postgresql or a Sql compact database. Each one is extremely similar(because its a service it has OnStart() and OnStop()...) to the other except for a few methods.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //normal code for database, in both services, but can't call from Interface
    }

     private void SetUniqueTimer()
    {
       //unique to certain database
    }
     private void SetUniqueTimer2()
    {
      //unique to other database
     }
```

I was wondering for future code re-usability if I could add an interface for different types of databases. I've combined the code from both into one service and depending on which database I need to communicate with in the future I can just add an interface and call the appropriate methods? Also because OnStart and OnStop are protected I can't call them, will they never start or stop? If I need to clarify please let me know. The main point I'm trying to do is make the service re-usable for future use, and easy maintainability 
Also if this is completely wrong direction to take please suggest better more efficient way

Comment: You're possibly looking for the [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Or if you want to go ORM, you could set this up so the objects look the same regardless of the underlying DBMS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx